# Submit form using javascript - AJAX

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have article entity, and I want to add one article via ajax.

I create a form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('descriptions');
}
```

This is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/article/add", name="app_admin_add_article")
 */
public function addCustomer(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleFormType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        /** @var Article $article */
        $article = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Article was successfully added!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_articles');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/articles/create.html.twig', [
        'articleForm'  =>  $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

How can I write the javascript to submit this form via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your ajax on your html using a button or another element

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
  url: "{{ url('app_admin_add_article') }}",
  data: {
     name: document.getElementById("nameInput").value,
     description: document.getElementById("descriptionInput").value
  },
  success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
  },
  error: function(err) {
     alert(err);
  }
});
```

and get the data sent by ajax in your controller

```
/**
* @Route("/admin/article/add", name="app_admin_add_article")
*/
public function addCustomer(Request $request)
{
    // throw exception if not ajax call
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $name = $request->request->get('name');
    $description = $request->request->get('description');

    $article = new Article();
    $article->setName($name);
    $article->setDescription($description);

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($article);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return new Response('Article created');
}
```

This is just a basic example without validating the input values and considering your class extends Controller

Answer (score 0):

i guess you ajax request should look somthing like this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $("form").attr("action"),
  data: $("form").serialize(), 
  //or your custom data either as object {foo: "bar", ...} or foo=bar&...
  success: function(response) { ... },
});
```

and you have to fire it with on click function on the submit button after preventing default for the button :

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

and in this case you have to change your controller logic.
but if i may ask why do you want to submit with ajax ?